# My friend is making a websocket server and it's not working

Tags: websocket

My friend made this WebSocket server for MineCraft and it doesn't work. He won't be on for a while so I decided to come to here. Can anyone help?

```
// Minecraft Bedrock WebSocket Server

const webSocket = require('websocket');
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const wss = new webSocket.server({port: 8000 });
try {
  console.log("Server is running on your_ip:8000");

  wss.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log("A client is opening a connection");

    const command = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        rl.question(`Command: /`, (cmd) => {

          // log user details
          //console.log(`\nYour INPUT: /${cmd}`);

          // Send command
          socket.send(JSON.stringify(
            {
              "body": {
                "origin": {
                  "type": "player"
                },
                "commandLine": `${cmd}`,
                "version": 1
              },
              "header": {
                "requestId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "messagePurpose": "commandRequest",
                "version": 1,
                "messageType": "commandRequest"
              }
            }
          ));

          console.log("Command sent\n\n");

          resolve();
        });
      });
    }

    async function askCommands() {
      while (true) {
        await command();
      }
    }
    
    // Run async function
    askCommands();

    socket.on('message', function incoming(message) {
      console.log('\nreceived: %s', message);
    });

    process.on('SIGINT', function() {
      console.log("\nInterrupt Ctrl-C");
      process.exit();
    });
  });

  wss.off;
} catch(E) {
  console.log(E);
}
```

This is the error in Visual Studio Code:

```
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
c:\Users\*****\Downloads\wsserver-bedrock-master\wsserver-bedrock-master\node_modules\websocket\lib\WebSocketServer.js:150
        throw new Error('You must specify an httpServer on which to mount the WebSocket server.');
        ^

Error: You must specify an httpServer on which to mount the WebSocket server.
    at WebSocketServer.mount (c:\Users\*****\Downloads\wsserver-bedrock-master\wsserver-bedrock-master\node_modules\websocket\lib\WebSocketServer.js:150:15)
    at new WebSocketServer (c:\Users\*****\Downloads\wsserver-bedrock-master\wsserver-bedrock-master\node_modules\websocket\lib\WebSocketServer.js:36:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\*****\Downloads\wsserver-bedrock-master\wsserver-bedrock-master\wsserver.js:11:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught Error: You must specify an httpServer on which to mount the WebSocket server.
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
```

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: Ive never really touched javascript/node.js so Ill just you his video and github for his code.
https://youtu.be/csvwK9LUq9s
https://github.com/sidious38/wsserver-bedrock

Comment: Like the error message says, you need to "specify an httpServer on which to mount the WebSocket server".  Create an `http` server first, then assign it to the WebSocket server. See the example in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just code like this.
In Client Side code should be like
[REF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co5OX.png)

And Server will be like this
[REF 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPHkT.png)